# If i want to create a static object reference same as out in System.out.println how can i do that

Tags: java

As System out print() statement in java  **out** is static reference. I want to create a static object reference how could i do.I had tried to make a object reference as static it is showing error

Comment: Post some code. We cannot provide an answer unless you show us what you tried and the errors that it produced. There is nothing special about `System.out`.

Comment: Post what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Just define it as public static:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static Integer myStaticReference = new Integer(7);
}
```